# Group values by continuous periods in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions

Consider this schema of a BigQuery table:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|ServiceId |UserId |Date                |
+---------------------------------------+
|s1        |u1     |2016|09|01 00:00:00 |
|s1        |u1     |2016|09|02 00:00:00 |
|s1        |u2     |2016|09|02 12:00:00 |
|s1        |u2     |2016|09|05 00:00:00 |
|s1        |u1     |2016|09|10 12:00:00 |
|s2        |u1     |2016|09|06 00:00:00 |
|s2        |u2     |2016|09|10 00:00:00 |
|s2        |u2     |2016|09|10 12:00:00 |
|s2        |u2     |2016|09|11 12:00:00 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

It illustrates the usage of certain resource of the system by an identified user. It works like a log of activities.

I need a query that allows me to retrieve the continuous usage of a resource over time. Since the table doesn't contain "start" and "end" dates, the end is considered to be the last logged day in the period.

Two dates are considered consecutive if they are at most 24 hours away from each other.

This is the expected output of such query with the given table:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|ServiceId  |UserId |StartDate           |EndDate             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|s1         |u1     |2016|09|01 00:00:00 |2016|09|02 00:00:00 |
|s1         |u2     |2016|09|02 12:00:00 |2016|09|02 12:00:00 |
|s1         |u2     |2016|09|05 00:00:00 |2016|09|05 00:00:00 |
|s1         |u1     |2016|09|10 12:00:00 |2016|09|10 12:00:00 |
|s2         |u1     |2016|09|06 00:00:00 |2016|09|06 00:00:00 |
|s2         |u2     |2016|09|10 00:00:00 |2016|09|11 12:00:00 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In other words: I need to identify periods of continuous usage of a service by an user.

The documentation of window functions on BigQuery ([here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#analytic-functions)) doesn't have clear examples of this kind of use case (in fact, they don't have examples with dates at all).

How that can be done using BigQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think it would look something like this:

```
select serviceid, userid, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when dateadd(prev_date, 1, "hour") < date then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by serviceid, userid order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date) over (partition by serviceid, userid order by date) as prev_date
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by serviceid, userid, grp;
```

What this does is identify when there is greater than a 1-hour break, assigning a flag of 1 when this occurs.  Then it does a cumulative sum of the flag and uses it for aggregation.

Comment: I tried it, and it worked with some tweaks: `prev_date` should be enclosed with an `USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP` function (due to a bug with the `lag` function and timestamps, more info [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=204)), and the numbers inside the comparison should be switched (`then 1 else 0`).

Comment: Standard SQL does not have this problem, if it helps. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/